# Make a child-div the same height like the parent div without position:absolute

Tags: css, html, css-position, parent-child

Here is the Code:

```
 <div id="content" class="row shadow" >

    <div id="test2" class="col-lg-4">
      <p>dsfdsfasdfdasfdsafdsfasdf</p>
    </div>

    <div id="test3" class="col-lg-4" style="">
      <p>breerwwerewrqerewrqewqrwqer</p>
   </div>

    <div id="test4" class="col-lg-4">
      <h2>Directlinks</h2>
      <p>BRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR</p>
    </div>

 </div>
```

..and i want to set:

```css
border-right:1px solid #ddd;
```

to id #test2 and #test3

the problem is, that the div don't want to take the height with height:100% from the parent div which is fixed to the content.

if i give one test* an absolute position it takes the max height of the parent div, but i can't set all child div to absolute without destroying the auto fix to the screen for re-sizing.

Comment: So you are trying to achieve something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WU64s/)?

Comment: no, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/R8gH9/)



> if you enlarge it you can see the boarder-lines which are not have the same height as the parent div

Comment: check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/R8gH9/1/

Comment: awesome, thank you!

can you please explain me how/why/and what you did change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following code to [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/R8gH9/):

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    #content { overflow: hidden; }
    #test2, #test3, #test4 {
        margin-bottom: -1000px;
        padding-bottom: 1000px;
    }
}
```

The `padding-bottom: 1000px` adds a padding of 1000px to the bottom of each of your columns.

The `margin-bottom: -1000px;` basically removes this padding again by decreasing the height of each column by 1000px. Each column now has at least 1000px height (the padding + the content).

By giving the `#content` `overflow:hidden` you cant see the additional 1000px at the bottom of each column, so the columns seem to have all equal height (try removing the `overflow:hidden`) to see that they are still different.

The media query (`@media (min-width: 1200px)`) makes sure to only apply those additional rules when your columns should be displayed next to each other.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/R8gH9/3/

Comment: that's really clever, but there is no elegant art?

and thank you for the explaining!

Comment: There are a few other ways to achieve the same effect, check this page for an overview: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ . But the method i used is the easiest addition to the Bootstrap column implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't work is because the parent doesn't have a defined height. Percentage values are based on the explicit height (or width, for that matter) of the parent why nothing happens if you let it flow freely.

Typically, when working with column based layout like this, you can use the display: table and table-cell to achieve what you want. [I made a simple example to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/4PQUh/).

CSS:

```
.outer {
   display: table;
}
.col {
   display: table-cell;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="col">
        text<br/>
        text<br/>
        text<br/> 
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        text
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        text<br/>
        text<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

than set it to "position:relative;" or
"position:absolute; display:block;"

Comment: "without position:absolute" because this would be destroy the auto fix to the screen fuction.

Comment: yeah just position relative and than the child items will use the height from their parent div...

Comment: i set #content to position: relative but the child div won't take the heigh of his parent